# parts and products relational schema

Tags: relational-database

I have a requirement for inventory management where we need to track parts and products (Finish goods) for which I think of tables as given below,

```
Part_Category {id, code, name}
Parts {id, code, name, description, part_cat_id, manufacturer_id, is_salable}
FG_Category {id, code, name}
Finish_Good {id, code, name, fg_cat_id, is_part_also}
```

The *is_salable* flag is used to say that this part can be sold to customer directly and *is_part_also* indicates that it is a sub-assembly (used as part in some another FG)

The use cases are,

1. Parts (raw materials) are issued for production
2. if FG is a sub-assembly (is_part_also), then that can be issued for production
3. some parts are directly sold to customers (like FG sold earlier requires a servicing and the firm should be able to sell a part required for this)
4. FGs are anyway sold directly to customers

The problem I have (using relational based schema) are -

- is this the best way to store and track part inventory that are salable as well as are used for production
- what is the best way to store and track FG inventory if it is a semi-finished good that can be sold as well as can be issued for production

Assuming that I need to issue all parts from Parts table and all items are sold from Finish_Good table, I have following problems,

- managing quantities
- since parts are issued from Parts table, not able to issue semi-finished goods from Finish_Good table for production
- since salable parts are also in Parts table, they can not be sold
- the inventory value be accounted in one place only (if a part is salable, its value is shown under FG stock and the semi-finished product value under Parts stock)

For now, I'm thinking of copying over the semi-finished FGs to Parts table in the application internally when they are produced and salable parts to the Finish_Good table (when they are received) so that they are all available at the right places. But these operations are atomic and appears error prone! But the quantities should also be shown under one accordingly (either Parts or in Finish_Good)

Is there a better design for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed the above use case by simplifying the overall table structure and by defining a *process* around the sales & raw material (RM) issue for production.

- Storing the available quantity of RMs only in Parts & FGs in
  Finish_Good table
- Transactions such as parts issue will only deal
  with Parts table
- Sales will only deal with Finish_Good table
- Transactions need not decrement/ increment quantity from multiple tables
- Defined a process where required quantity of the saleable RM should be
  moved to Finish_Good before a sale and required quantity of semi-finished good to be moved to Part table for use in production

This has simplified the table structure as well as helped in maintaining correct inventory information across the system. This also helped in audit reconciliation where the inventory quantity may be corrected at one place.